# Does the C++ guarantee an ordering of cstdint sizeof?

Tags: c++, c++11, integer, standards, sizeof

Does the C++ standard guarantee that:

```
sizeof(uint8_t) <= sizeof(uint16_t) <= sizeof(uint32_t) <= sizeof(uint64_t)
sizeof(uint_least8_t) <= sizeof(uint_least16_t) <= sizeof(uint_least32_t) <= sizeof(uint_least64_t)
sizeof(uint_fast8_t) <= sizeof(uint_fast16_t) <= sizeof(uint_fast32_t) <= sizeof(uint_fast64_t)
```

If not, what guarantees does it provide?
(extracts from the standard are welcome)

Comment: I actually don't know, but here are a couple of rules of thumb... 1. If it would be ridiculous for this not to be the case, it's probably in the standard, or at least in every compiler you're likely to use 2. If you're still not 100% sure - have your code assert it when it comes up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one is guaranteed, iff those types exist. (They may not exist if the system can't provide them).

The second one, `least` , is guaranteed. Here is the text for the unsigned case (the signed text is analogous):

> The typedef name uint_leastN_t designates an unsigned integer type with a width
>   of at least N, such that no unsigned integer type with lesser size has at least the specified
>   width.

The third one, `fast`: it doesn't seem to be exactly specified, but it says:

> The typedef name int_fastN_t designates the fastest signed integer type with a width of at least N

If we assume that this text is to be taken literally then it would give the guarantee; although the associated footnote suggests that the compiler has a bit more latitude. Nevertheless it seems very unlikely that an implementation would do something like make `fast16_t` be 64-bit, and `fast32_t` be 32-bit.

NB. These quotes are from ISO C99, which the C++ standard refers to for these definitions.

Comment: By what sentence is the second one guaranteed?

Comment: To be more specific: int8_t, int16_t, etc. are exact-sized types. That means int8_t is always exactly 8 bits, int16_t is always exactly 16 bits, and so on.